# What is the radius of convergence, $R$, of the Taylor series of the ordinary hypergeometric function?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, power-series, hypergeometric-function

I'm trying to compute the Radius of convergence of:

$$_2F_1(a,b;c;x) = 1+\frac{ab}{1!c}x+\frac{a(a+1)b(b+1)}{2!c(c+1)}x^2+\ldots+\frac{a(a+1)\cdots(a+n-1)b(b+1)\cdots(b+n-1)}{n!c(c+1)\cdots(c+n-1)}x^n+\ldots$$

Where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are real parameters, and $c$ is not a negative integer.

1. First, I used the formula of the radius of convergence of a power series: $R= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{|a_n|}{|a_{n+1}|}$; which gave me:

$
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} |\frac{(a+n-1)(b+n-1)}{n!(c+n-1)}| ÷ |\frac{(a+(n+1)-1)(b+(n+1)-1)}{(n+1)!(c+(n+1)-1)}|
$ (I'm not sure I have applied it correctly since the formula that's given is not in sigma notation...)

2. After doing some simplification, I had:

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{(a+n-1)(b+n-1)(c+n)(n+1)}{(a+n)(b+n)(c+n-1)}$; which gave me:

3. $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{(a+n-1)(b+n-1)(c+n)(n+1)}{(a+n)(b+n)(c+n-1)} = \infty
   $

However, the answer of the problem is $R=1$ so... here I am, trying to understand why.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance :D

Comment: What you use as $a_n$ during the ratio test is not the general term of the hypergeometric series. Can you see that if $a_n$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ then $$
a_{n + 1}  = a_n \frac{{(a + n)(b + n)}}{{(c + n)(n + 1)}}\,?
$$

Comment: The formula you used for $a_n$ does not match the terms of the series.

Comment: @elemelons thank you for your comment, to be honest, I didn't know what formula to use for $a_n$, I just kinda guessed that it would work if I used it, however, it's clearly not the case :( Thank you for pointing out my dumb mistake

Comment: @Gary Thank you for your comment, yes you're completely correct, I just kinda guessed that it would work if I used that general term, however, it's clearly not the case. Thank you for pointing out my dumb mistake though! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the $n$th coefficient of the series is a fraction with a bunch of terms, including all of the terms that appears in the formula for the previous coefficient, then the ratio between coefficients is simply the fraction consisting of only the new terms that appear. For example, we have

$$ a_2=\frac{a(a+1)\,b(b+1)}{c(c+1)\,1(1+1)}, \quad a_3=\frac{a(a+1)(a+2)\,b(b+1)(b+2)}{c(c+1)(c+2)\,1(1+1)(1+2)}, \quad \frac{a_3}{a_2}=\frac{(a+2)(b+2)}{(c+2)(1+2)}. $$

More generally, the ratio is

$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(a+n)(b+n)}{(c+n)(1+n)}. $$

Comment: Thank you @elemelons, I hadn't thought about that before, thank you for your answer! :D